# Symfony 2.1 : Test the prod mod => exception using the app.php controller calling ApcClassLoader->__construct

Tags: symfony-2.1, production-environment

Before deploying my symfony 2.1 version into my prod serveur, I wanted to test the behaviour of the prod env.

So I have done a `php app/console cache:clear --env=prod --no-debug`, after a `php app/console assets:install web` and now when I'm calling the app controller I have this error.

Google for this case is not my friend :-(

> ## 0 /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/myapp/web/app.php(13): Symfony\Component\ClassLoader\ApcClassLoader->__construct('sf2', Object(Composer\Autoload\ClassLoader))
>
> ## 1 {main}

Here my app.php file

> use Symfony\Component\ClassLoader\ApcClassLoader; use
>   Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
>
> $loader = require_once **DIR**.'/../app/bootstrap.php.cache';
>
> // Use APC for autoloading to improve performance // Change 'sf2' by
>   the prefix you want in order to prevent key conflict with another
>   application /* $loader = new ApcClassLoader('sf2', $loader);
>   $loader->register(true);
>   */
>
> require_once **DIR**.'/../app/AppKernel.php'; 
>   //require_once  **DIR**.'/../app/AppCache.php';
>
> $kernel = new AppKernel('prod', false); 
>   $kernel->loadClassCache();
>
> //$kernel = new AppCache($kernel); 
>   $request = Request::createFromGlobals(); 
>   $response = $kernel->handle($request);
>   $response->send(); 
>   $kernel->terminate($request, $response);

Any help would be very cool

Thanks
Sam

Comment: Is it the whole error message? Can you post here your `web/app.php`?

Comment: Yes this is the only message

Answer (score 0):

It's failing on `ApcClassLoader` do you have APC installed? try restart apache.

We can't really see if those APC lines are commented out of not in your `app.php`, lines return are all messy.

Comment: It's definitely something with APC, try deleting those line just to make sure. what do you mean by "and now when I'm calling the app controller I have this error." did you change the redirect in the `.htaccess`?

Comment: I have removed all values concerning APC and still the same error. I havent change the htaccess. => it's seems that is the $kernel->loadClassCache(); which is wrong